# Переадресация по ссылке

Tags: php, .htaccess

Подскажите, как сделать так чтобы пользователь зашедший по ссылке в которой содержится /content/ переходил на ту же самую ссылку ну уже без /content/ этой части. Например сайт/content/test на сайт/test.

Comment: вам  нужно чтобы его перенаправляло на новую ссылку целиком, или чтобы по исходной ссылке открывался контент второй?

Comment: `RedirectMatch` из `mod_alias` вам вероятно поможет.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^/content/(.*)$  /$1
```